# <appSettings> <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"/>

Tags: c#, asp.net

Why the error goes away when we add this in the web.config file.

when i am setting value to "Webform" its showing error again.

what is the reason for that.

Comment: Please have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. knowing how to ask question will help you to get the right answer you are looking for.

Comment: Moreover, do you confirm the value is WebForms and not Webforms? mind the Uppercase in Forms